# Flutter build error "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

Tags: flutter

Guys I'm completely new to flutter and whenever I try and run all I got same error, I tried everything I could find on net, but it still doesn't work. PLZ help

[This is the output of Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh23P.png)

[this is the output of logcat-Verbose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKPLS.png)

Comment: as the error message says, your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Comment: @BoygeniusDexter thx for help , but do we  need java for flutter ?

Comment: you need java for Gradle, and for building the Android app as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Android Studio`
2. Go to `File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure/JDK Location`
3. and copy whatever string is specified there

In the file locator directory window, right-click on `This PC`

`Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables... -> System Variables`

Click on the `New` button under System Variables, then type and paste respectively:

Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`

Variable value: `Which you have copied earlier in step 3`

Comment: i did the same but i still get the same thing . do i need to install java separately? (don't mind these silly questions , i'm a noob )